# Custom google image search on mobile device

Tags: android, search, google-api

I just need the correct format of the request - https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?
key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=flowers&alt=json.

My app will simply make a request with the search phrase and get a callback in JSON. I already connect Google Custom Search to my account, fill in the payment details and get all the keys.
I use the key for Android apps (with certificates), but get the response "Access Not Configured" after call the request in the browser.

How to create a query string to request the API? How can I get the parameter cx?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of Google. The problem was solved only completely removing default project and create a new one.